# How can we make it even more clear that this is a site for Arduino?

Tags: discussion

Today I first bumped into a question about the Intel Edison, and just now one about the Raspberry Pi. Apparently the word "Arduino" doesn't make it clear that this is about, erm, Arduino.
How can we make this more clear (if possible), and keep questions about other platforms out?

(I flagged both questions for migration to http://electronics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: All SE sites have blatantly off topic questions from users who think they're on topic... I think most new people perceive the scope a lot more loosely than it actually is--myself included. The hard questions to steer people away from are the questions that have an Arduino element but are off topic (like programming a display app on a computer that communicates with an Arduino).

Comment: By the way, isn't there a SE site for Pi question and shouldn't any such questions be migrated to that?

Answer (score 2):

We've had similar issues with people asking Android questions in the past. I'm not sure there's much we can do to stop people from making that mistake. Part of the confusion might come from the fact that all Stack Exchange sites have exactly the same design during beta.

As a side note, the Intel Edison isn't necessarily off-topic here. It's [officially certified](http://www.arduino.cc/en/ArduinoCertified/Products) as an Arduino-compatible product. Obviously it depends on the context of the individual question though, as it can certainly be used in non-Arduino ways too.

Comment: The "officially certified" is of course a bad joke. Their own Arduino is so poorly documented that it wouldn't pass any certification at all. And have you read the 4 requirements for certification? There's nothing about compatibility.

Comment: I just flagged <http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/15984/unable-to-set-up-intel-edison-on-windows> as off-topic. As far as I can see the Intel Edison is just leveraging (pfft, is that a word?) off the Arduino name. It - at best - seems to be "compatible with the Arduino IDE".